# could someone explain this type error "Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `a0 -> c0' "

Tags: haskell

Here's the type error I am getting, followed by the code in question. This may be due to an incorrect use of function composition, if so I'd like an explanation as to how I can fix that. If it's something else, I'd like to talk about that too.

```
frameworkDaemon.lhs:125:5:
Couldn't match expected type `IO ()' with actual type `a0 -> c0'
In the expression: popJobState . popProcessConfig . readJobFile
In an equation for `makeJobState':
    makeJobState world
      = popJobState . popProcessConfig . readJobFile
      where
          readJobFile
            = do { let ...;
                   .... }
            where
                getFileContents (x : xs) = readFile (ixiaRoot ++ "/" ++ (show x))
          popProcessConfig = undefined
          popJobState = undefined
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.

```
 makeJobState :: JobState -> IO ()
 makeJobState world =
   popJobState . popProcessConfig . readJobFile -- f .g . h -> f(g(h))
      where readJobFile = do
               let directoryPath = ixiaRoot ++ "/jobs"
                   processedPath = map (directoryPath </>) . filter (`notElem` [".",".."])
               jobFileNames <- processedPath <$> getDirectoryContents directoryPath
               let numStrings = map (last . splitOn "/") jobFileNames
                   sortJobNumbers = map read numStrings :: [Int]
               getFileContents $ sort $ sortJobNumbers
                       where getFileContents (x:xs) = readFile (ixiaRoot ++ "/" ++ (show x))

            popProcessConfig = undefined
            popJobState =  undefined
```

Comment: I fixed it this way, it was an misuse of (.) 
  popJobState $ popProcessConfig $ readJobFile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sepp2k said, `f.g.h` is a function, `\x -> f $ g $ h x`. It seems that `readJobFile` is `IO String`, though, not `IO ()`.

But it doesn't complain about expecting a function. It explains about having *inferred* a function, and having expected an `IO ()`. It's inferred a function because your chain of compositions is just that---a function, so the result of applying `makeJobState` to a `JobState` value is (or would be) a function, not an IO action.

It seems as if what you want isn't function composition but monadic composition, something like `makeJobState world = readJobFile >>= popProcessConfig >>= popJobState` (with the `world` parameter actually being used at some point, though it's not really obvious to me where it should go. And that might not be the preferred order; it's hard to tell since the other two variables are undefined.) Since `readJobFile` is `IO String`, you'd want `popProcessConfig` to be `String -> IO a` and `popJobState` to be `a -> IO ()`. That would result in an overall type of `JobState -> IO ()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
-- f .g . h -> f(g(h))
```

`f . g . h` is **not** equivalent to `f(g(h))`, it's equivalent to `\x -> f(g(h x))`, so `h` needs to be a function, but `readJobFile` (which is the `h` in your example) is an `IO ()`. That's why the error message complains about expecting a function where you gave it an `IO ()`.